# How can I get/display WooCommerce bestselling products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am developing a WooCommerce eBook store and I would like to display the list of best seller product on my home page.

How can I do that? can I do it with a custom WP_Query? Any other ways?

Comment: create a category for a best sellers and do a custom loop on your product post type and category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get Best seller products, you can use different ways:

**A WordPress WP_Query *(limited here to 20 bestselling products)*:**

```
$query_args =  array(
   'posts_per_page' =>  20, // -1 (for all)
   'post_type'      =>  array( 'product' ),
   'post_status'    =>  'publish',
   'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
   'order'          => 'DESC',
   'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

// Your product data
the_title(); // Output product title

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

else :
// No post found

endif;
```

**A WooCommerce Shordcode *(the 20 best selling products)*:**

```
[products best_selling limit="20"]
```

Documentation:

- [Woocommerce Shortcodes (since version 3.2)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9)
- [`WC_Shortcode_Products` `set_best_selling_products_query_args()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php#L388-L398)